# How to add path to new File in Java

Tags: java, file, filereader

I have something like this:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Test\eclipse_workspace\Example\text.txt");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You already did it. What is your question ?

Comment: Probably you can't because it's not the same file.

Comment: Maybe you mean that you wish the full path to the file ? If you got this file as `File`-Object than you can try `.getAbsolutePath()` - if you want to build the path to and only know the name of the file you can try:
`String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//test.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Counterslash is a character which has to be escaped, as well as being the character used to escape characters. So, in order to get

```
File file = new File("C:\Users\Test\eclipse_workspace\Example\text.txt");
```

to work, you must escape every counterslash. Just like this:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Test\\eclipse_workspace\\Example\\text.txt");
```